# Convert scalar field into probability density function. (Either analytic or numerical)

Tags: integration, statistics, numerical-calculus

I have a scalar field $f(x,y,z)$ defined over a finite region, and what's important to me is the profile of $P(f)$ against $f$ where $P(f_0)$ is the probability density of $f_0$.

Whilst I (think I) can write down that

$$P(f_0) = \frac{1}{V} \int \delta(f_0-f) \rm{d}xyz,$$

with $V$ as the volume of my region,

This in an incredibly difficult integral that I really have no hope of computing.

The specific function I'm dealing with is

$$f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\left(1-\frac{3x^2}{x^2 + y^2+z^2}\right)$$.

The region is a circle of sphere r but centred at $(x_0,0,0)$ and **not** at the origin.

Comment: The probability distribution of a field is a specialized topic. If I understand correctly you have the correct basic idea but you need a generalization of the dirac delta function for a field, "the dirac delta functional". I suggest to check out " the statistical physics of polymers" by kawakatsu (2001) or "the statistical physics of fields" by Kardar. This said I'm a bit confused because you have a deterministic field. Why do you care about its probability distribution? It'll have no variance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll check those out at some point for sure.

To be honest I gave up on the maths and ended up just numerically sampling random points and producing a histogram that way. 

The reason that I care is because I'm trying to make an approximation which is only valid if over my region there is something sort of like a Gaussian distribution over the possible values of f. FYI, there wasn't :(

Comment: So you want the probability distribution of values the field takes on as you vary $x$, $y$, and $z$ across your domain? If so, this means I misunderstood! I thought you meant the distribution of configurations the field takes on -- much more complicated! In this case the integral you set up seems correct to me. I guess that you should be able to conduct it in spherical coordinates easily enough, although the integration domain might be challenging.